# Fire an automated email when database updated?

Tags: php, javascript, email

I am trying to figure out the best way to send an automated email to a customer when we update our database with "frames in" i'm thinking javascript & php but don't really know how to implement as a nobo!?

#### My HTML Form showing checkbox that needs to fire email (only partially shown due to length)

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="form" method="POST"> 
<input name="frame_in" type="checkbox" id="long_tiny" value="yes" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_Recordset1['frame_in'],"yes"))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> />
<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form">
</form>
```

#### The php mail script (Not sure if completely correct)

```
$mailTo = $row_customer['email'];
$subject = 'Your Frames Now in!!';
$cName = $row_Recordset2['cName'];
$jobRef = $row_Recordset2['customer_ref'];
$ourRef = $row_Recordset2['our_ref'];
$jobTotal = $row_recordset2['amount'];
mail($mailTo, $subject,
$cName your job Ref: $jobref is now in
<br>
<h2>Details:</h2>
<p>Our ref: $ourRef<br>
Customer Ref: $jobref<br>
Job total: $jobtotal</p>
);
```

I really don't know how to tie it all together I'm guessing there would need to be error handling as not every customer has an email (But the error doesn't need to be shown)

Comment: This seems a bit too broad, what part do you have problems with? As I see it there is no need for additional javascript, you can handle everything from `$editFormAction`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mailTo = $row_customer['email'];
$subject = 'Your Frames Now in!!';
$cName = $row_Recordset2['cName'];
$jobRef = $row_Recordset2['customer_ref'];
$ourRef = $row_Recordset2['our_ref'];
$jobTotal = $row_recordset2['amount'];
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$message = "$cName your job Ref: $jobref is now in
<br>
<h2>Details:</h2>
<p>Our ref: $ourRef<br>
Customer Ref: $jobref<br>
Job total: $jobtotal</p>";
if($_POST['frame_in'] == "yes") {
mail($mailTo, $subject,$message, $headers); 
}
```

Comment: This looks like it could work but without sounding like a numpty is php and where would I have to put this?

Comment: this is PHP, it would go wherever the other PHP to handle the form goes. when the user hits submit $editFormAction should = name of php file, that is where this would go.

Comment: I have tried this but cant seem to get it to work would this be anything to do with the $_POST I get an undefined index error,  I have also tried to change it to $editFormAction I no longer get any obvious errors but no mail gets sent? Hope someone can help?

Comment: you need to learn more: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp, PHP.NET. Have fun

Comment: Working now thanks (didn't have sendmail installed) have been trying to get it to fire if frame_in="yes" and collected="no" any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. What you need to do is:

1. Process the form in `$editFormAction`
2. If `$_POST['frame_in']` is set, do the following:

   - Get all customers
   - Send an email to the ones with an e-mail address
3. Publish a warning on your site for logged-in users (or in general...) that do not have an email address registered.

No aditional javascript needed.

Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I have made a basic intranet system php/mysql where we can track our customer orders and would like to send the customer an automated email telling them there job is in when our office staff selects frames in check box. If there is no email address the script doesn't have to do anything (No errors or warnings as in house) but this is just out of my ability to put together

Answer (score 0):

You could try a database trigger that sends an email. The database itself would be sending out the e-mail, and would not involve php at all. This would also be more inclusive, as it would send an email regardless or who/what changes the field, including changes from PhpMyAdmin, or other webpages/scripts.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,33635,33635#msg-33635

This may be limited depending on your hosting environment. If you are using shared hosting, odds are you cannot utilize triggers for security reasons.